# How can I better sort and set wifi network preferences on Mac?

Tags: network, wifi, system-settings, preferences

The Advanced section of the Wifi - Network Preferences allows for dragging and dropping of known wifi networks in order to set a priority order for joining networks. (Networks higher in the list will be joined first, when multiple are available.)

[image: Advanced Wifi Network Preferences]

By default, newly joined networks are added to the end of the list. My problem is that I have hundreds of known networks and the list cannot be searched, nor can the window be made larger to allow for more effective scrolling.

I was wondering if there exists a better method, or perhaps a third-party app, that would give a better UI to search and re-sort known wifi networks. Let me know if this question would be better suited for [Software Recs SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Are you looking for a way to remove some of them, or just reorder?

Comment: @timothymh preferably both.

Comment: Thanks @yannisalexiou, but getting the file open is the easy part. The challenge for the OP, and me with 615 networks in my plist, is that using a text or plist editor like Xcode to edit a large relational set of data with non-human identifiable keys is impractical. The original question still stands ... Is there an existing tool that would allow us to efficiently manage and reorder the known network priority list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR;

The file that contains all the information about Known Networks is `com.apple.airport.preferences.plist` and you can find it under `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/`

**How to change the order / Delete a network from the order:**

1. Open finder.
2. From Menu Bar select `Go -> Go To Folder`.
3. Copy paste this path `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/`.
4. Locate the file `com.apple.airport.preferences.plist` and make a copy of it with a name like `com.apple.airport.preferencesOLD.plist` ( for backup just in case).
5. Move the original file from the previous step to your desktop to enable
   editing.
6. Open the file with Xcode (or any other text editor app)
7. In `PreferredOrder` array you can see the full list in descending
   sort.
8. Change the order or delete a network if you don't want it in the
   order.
9. Move the `com.apple.airport.preferences.plist` back to
   `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/` folder

As you can see the value of each item is wifi's ssid.

You can match wifi ssid with yours wifi name from the dictionary `KnownNetworks` (above of `PreferredOrder` in `com.apple.airport.preferences.plist` file).